# get HEX data from server.arg() function in ESP8266WebServer library

Tags: arduino-esp8266

I receive data from an Editbox in my web page with:

```
String inputData = server.arg("editBox1");
```

But I think that it receives HEX data

for example:

When my input data is: 12345%6789

by server.arg() function

received data: 12345g89 (67 is HEX of 'g')

other example:

input data: 12345#6789 or 12345+6789

received data: 12345

Comment: you have to encode the data. % a # are characters used to encode url

Comment: doesn't ESP8266WebServer decode the parameters automaticaly?

Comment: deleted comment: Thanks :) - I found 'encodeURIComponent(uri)' for js, but I could not find function or library to decode in arduino...

Comment: decode by ESP8266WebServer? Testing...

Comment: your problem was that your stream was decoded even if it was not encoded but contained the character used in encoding